# How to declare GeckoFX Web Browser with GeckoFX / XULRunner 29?

Tags: .net, geckofx

How do you declare the GeckoFX Web Browser with GeckoFX / XULRunner 29? I don't want to use the Web Browser control. I'd like to use it in code. They changed the way you declare it. It used to be GeckoWebBrowser.

Comment: The source for the [current test application](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/src/23da3d433fa801891a3a1f7a735f926b03f2cbbf/GeckoFxTest/Main.cs?at=default) lists ```var browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();``` so probably that's not your problem. Can you write more?

Comment: Do you mean to initialize GeckoFx web browser controll programmatically to use it on the form?